# How do I navigate a table without any easily accessible distinctions?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm working on a small project to learn python better (right now BeautifulSoup), and got stuck with no idea how to move forward. I am trying to scrape data from [www.we.umg.edu.pl/ktm/konsultacje](http://www.we.umg.edu.pl/ktm/konsultacje).

As for now I have this part of code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Make a GET request to the URL
url = "https://we.umg.edu.pl/ktm/konsultacje"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

roomsProfessors = soup.find_all('h3')

# Lists for sorted data
professors = []
rooms = []

# Get data about rooms and professors and fill their lists
for roomProfessor in roomsProfessors:
    professor = []

    for child in roomProfessor:
        if child.name == 'br':
            continue

        child = child.string.replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '')

        if 'pok.' in child:
            rooms.append(child)
        else:
            professor.append(child)
        
    professors.append(professor)
```

However I got stuck right now. I want to extract weekdays or dates with the corresponding hour, but have no idea how to do it.

I noticed that the part with professor and their hours is separated with one shorter tr with just one td inside instead of usual two, but have no idea how to use it.

Is there some smart way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your expected output should look like, but you could iterate with `find_next_siblings()` or `previous_siblings()`

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://we.umg.edu.pl/ktm/konsultacje"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
data = []
for p in soup.select('tr:has(h3)'):
    d ={
        'prof': p.h3.contents[0].strip(),
        'room': p.h3.contents[-1].strip(),
        'times': []
    }

    for e in p.find_next_siblings('tr'):
        if e.h3:
            break
        if len(e.text.strip()) > 1 and not e.h5:
            d['times'].append(e.get_text('|',strip=True))
    data.append(d)
data
```

###### Output

```
[{'prof': 'dr hab. inż. Andrzej Borys, prof. UMG',
  'room': 'pok. C28',
  'times': ['czwartek|12.00-14.00',
   '11.03|09.00-10.00',
   '25.03|09.00-10.00',
   '15.04|09.00-10.00',
   '29.04|09.00-10.00',
   '10.06|10.00-11.00']},
 {'prof': 'mgr inż. Dawid Budnarowski',
  'room': 'pok. C-51',
  'times': ['wtorek|środa|11.00-12.00|11.00-12.00']},
 {'prof': 'dr inż. Tomasz Ciszewski',
  'room': 'pok. C345',
  'times': ['środa|15.00-17.00']},
 {'prof': 'dr inż. Wiesław Citko',
  'room': 'pok. C341',
  'times': ['czwartek|9.00-11.00',
   '04.03|11.00-12.00',
   '01.04|10.00-11.00',
   '20.05|12.00-13.00',
   '16.06|19.00-20.00',
   '07.07|16.00-17.00']},...]
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I need, but there is a problem:
In the line "'prof': p.h3.contents[0].strip()," or "'room': p.h3.contents[-1].strip()," there is an error with the .contents[0] part that says:
"contents" is not a known member of "None"PylancereportOptionalMemberAccess.
Why doesn't it work for me and it does for you?

Comment: Not sure, what pylance is doing exactly and if your bs4 version is up to date - You also could use `d ={
        'prof': list(p.h3.stripped_strings)[0],
        'room': list(p.h3.stripped_strings)[-1],
        'times': []
    }`

Comment: I don't know neither, but I turns out that this mistake is caused by the VS Code interpreter. If I run the program using terminal everything works fine. Huge thanks for the help, the program runs great <3

Comment: Turns out when installing Python extension it also installs Pylance, which messed up my linter and shown errors where there weren't any. Uninstalling resolved problems

Comment: Thank you for further research that has brought this fact with `Pylance` to light and sharing it with us.

Answer (score 1):

You're not saying what your expected output should be, but here's a brute force approach with `pandas`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate

konsultacje = "https://we.umg.edu.pl/ktm/konsultacje"
df = (
    pd
    .read_html(requests.get(konsultacje).text, flavor="lxml")[0]
    .dropna(axis=0, how="all")
)
df.columns = ["Kolumna 1", "Kolumna 2"]
df = df[["Kolumna 1", "Kolumna 2"]]
print(tabulate(df, headers="keys", tablefmt="psql", showindex=False))
```

Output:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Kolumna 1                                              | Kolumna 2                                              |
|--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------|
| dr hab. inż. Andrzej Borys, prof. UMG  pok. C28        | dr hab. inż. Andrzej Borys, prof. UMG  pok. C28        |
| studia stacjonarne                                     | studia stacjonarne                                     |
| czwartek                                               | 12.00-14.00                                            |
| studia niestacjonarne                                  | studia niestacjonarne                                  |
| 11.03                                                  | 09.00-10.00                                            |
| 25.03                                                  | 09.00-10.00                                            |
| 15.04                                                  | 09.00-10.00                                            |
| 29.04                                                  | 09.00-10.00                                            |
| 10.06                                                  | 10.00-11.00                                            |
| mgr inż. Dawid Budnarowski  pok. C-51                  | mgr inż. Dawid Budnarowski  pok. C-51                  |
| studia stacjonarne                                     | studia stacjonarne                                     |
| wtorek  środa                                          | 11.00-12.00  11.00-12.00                               |
| dr inż. Tomasz Ciszewski  pok. C345                    | dr inż. Tomasz Ciszewski  pok. C345                    |
| studia stacjonarne                                     | studia stacjonarne                                     |
| środa                                                  | 15.00-17.00                                            |
| dr inż. Wiesław Citko  pok. C341                       | dr inż. Wiesław Citko  pok. C341                       |
| studia stacjonarne                                     | studia stacjonarne                                     |
| czwartek                                               | 9.00-11.00                                             |
| studia niestacjonarne                                  | studia niestacjonarne                                  |
| 04.03                                                  | 11.00-12.00                                            |
| 01.04                                                  | 10.00-11.00                                            |
| 20.05                                                  | 12.00-13.00                                            |
| 16.06                                                  | 19.00-20.00                                            |
| 07.07                                                  | 16.00-17.00                                            |
| dr inż. Piotr Kaczorek  pok. C341                      | dr inż. Piotr Kaczorek  pok. C341                      |
| studia stacjonarne                                     | studia stacjonarne                                     |
| czwartek                                               | 11.00-13.00                                            |
| studia niestacjonarne                                  | studia niestacjonarne                                  |
| 18.03                                                  | 11.00-12.00                                            |
| 23.04                                                  | 19.00-20.00                                            |
| 13.05                                                  | 13.00-14.00                                            |
| 10.06                                                  | 12.00-13.00                                            |
| dr inż. Karol Korcz, prof. UMG  pok. C349              | dr inż. Karol Korcz, prof. UMG  pok. C349              |
| studia stacjonarne                                     | studia stacjonarne                                     |
| czwartek                                               | 11.00-13.00                                            |
| studia niestacjonarne                                  | studia niestacjonarne                                  |
| 05.03                                                  | 13.00-14.00                                            |
| 19.03                                                  | 13.00-14.00                                            |
| 23.04                                                  | 14.00-15.00                                            |
| 07.05                                                  | 12.00-13.00                                            |
| 03.06                                                  | 14.00-16.00                                            |
| dr inż. Ewa Krac  pok. C51                             | dr inż. Ewa Krac  pok. C51                             |
| studia stacjonarne                                     | studia stacjonarne                                     |
| środa  piątek                                          | 10.30-11.30  10.30-11.30                               |
| studia niestacjonarne                                  | studia niestacjonarne                                  |
| 19.03                                                  | 13.00-14.00                                            |
| 23.04                                                  | 13.00-14.00                                            |
| 04.06                                                  | 14.00.15.00                                            |
| dr inż. Stanisław Lindner  pok. C344                   | dr inż. Stanisław Lindner  pok. C344                   |
| studia stacjonarne                                     | studia stacjonarne                                     |
| czwartek                                               | 13.00-15.00                                            |
| studia niestacjonarne                                  | studia niestacjonarne                                  |
| 19.03                                                  | 12.00-13.00                                            |
| 22.04                                                  | 10.00-11.00                                            |
| 06.05                                                  | 11.00-12.00                                            |
| 04.06                                                  | 11.00-12.00                                            |
| 18.06                                                  | 11.00-12.00                                            |
| dr inż. Andrzej Łuksza  pok. C341                      | dr inż. Andrzej Łuksza  pok. C341                      |
| studia stacjonarne                                     | studia stacjonarne                                     |
| środa                                                  | 11.00-13.00                                            |
| studia niestacjonarne                                  | studia niestacjonarne                                  |
| 19.03                                                  | 13.00-14.00                                            |
| 23.04                                                  | 13.00-14.00                                            |
| 06.05                                                  | 14.00-15.00                                            |
| 17.06                                                  | 11.00-12.00                                            |
| dr inż. Beata Pałczyńska  pok. C339                    | dr inż. Beata Pałczyńska  pok. C339                    |
| studia stacjonarne                                     | studia stacjonarne                                     |
| środa                                                  | 13.00-14.00                                            |
| dr inż. Dorota Rabczuk  pok. C339                      | dr inż. Dorota Rabczuk  pok. C339                      |
| studia stacjonarne                                     | studia stacjonarne                                     |
| wtorek                                                 | 14.00-16.00                                            |
| mgr inż. Wojciech Rabczuk  pok. C51                    | mgr inż. Wojciech Rabczuk  pok. C51                    |
| studia stacjonarne                                     | studia stacjonarne                                     |
| poniedziałek                                           | 7.00-8.00, 12.00-13.00                                 |
| studia niestacjonarne                                  | studia niestacjonarne                                  |
| 05.03                                                  | 07.00-08.00                                            |
| 19.03                                                  | 11.00-12.00                                            |
| dr hab. inż. Agnieszka Rybarczyk, prof. UMG  pok. C345 | dr hab. inż. Agnieszka Rybarczyk, prof. UMG  pok. C345 |
| studia stacjonarne                                     | studia stacjonarne                                     |
| piątek                                                 | 10.00-12.00                                            |
| dr hab. inż. Wiesław Sieńko, prof. UMG  pok. C208      | dr hab. inż. Wiesław Sieńko, prof. UMG  pok. C208      |
| studia stacjonarne                                     | studia stacjonarne                                     |
| czwartek                                               | 11.00-13.00                                            |
| studia niestacjonarne                                  | studia niestacjonarne                                  |
| 04.03                                                  | 14:00 - 15:00                                          |
| 18.03                                                  | 14:00 - 15:00                                          |
| 01.04                                                  | 12:00 - 13:00                                          |
| 06.05                                                  | 14:00 - 15:00                                          |
| 20.05                                                  | 15:00 - 16:00                                          |
| 03.06                                                  | 11:00 - 12:00                                          |
| mgr inż. Marta Szarmach  pok. C339                     | mgr inż. Marta Szarmach  pok. C339                     |
| studia stacjonarne                                     | studia stacjonarne                                     |
| wtorek                                                 | 10.00-12.00                                            |
| Agata Śledzińska-Płotczyk  pok. C-326                  | Agata Śledzińska-Płotczyk  pok. C-326                  |
| studia stacjonarne                                     | studia stacjonarne                                     |
| piątek                                                 | 15.30-16.30                                            |
| mgr inż. Marcin Waraksa  pok. C336                     | mgr inż. Marcin Waraksa  pok. C336                     |
| studia stacjonarne                                     | studia stacjonarne                                     |
| wtorek                                                 | 15.00-17.00                                            |
| studia niestacjonarne                                  | studia niestacjonarne                                  |
| 05.03                                                  | 14.00-15.00                                            |
| 19.03                                                  | 14.00-15.00                                            |
| 02.04                                                  | 16.00-17.00                                            |
| 14.04                                                  | 16.00-17.00                                            |
| 30.04                                                  | 13.00-14.00                                            |
| dr hab. inż. Andrzej Żak, prof. UMG  pok. C326         | dr hab. inż. Andrzej Żak, prof. UMG  pok. C326         |
| studia stacjonarne                                     | studia stacjonarne                                     |
| wtorek                                                 | 16.00-18.00                                            |
| studia niestacjonarne                                  | studia niestacjonarne                                  |
| 04.03                                                  | 16.00-18.00                                            |
| 05.03                                                  | 10.00-11.00                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```